# Optimal design of html page for GSA?

Tags: google-search-appliance

We need to index a site with GSA. So the plan is to build a HTML page that we add what needs to be indexed.

We mainly need to index documents and they are all saves as "strange" targets. There is a link-generator on the website that will provide the actual binary.

It works in a way. Our HTML file has a bunch of list entries:

```
<li><a href='/download/getBinary/tcm:1146-200516?disposition=inline'>
CustomCode_on_page_V1.0.docx</a></li>
```

GSA index some of the content to extract content.And this is fine in the way we can search for docx and get the XML. The search result outputs the T and S tag.

But what I miss is the "CustomCode_on_page_V1.0.docx" in the output. Nor can I search on phrase customcode.

To optimize and get the filename as well - what is the optimal/best route forward?

I have pdf and office docs that I need to index and be able to search on. I get them indexed but the Title is what I want to be.. as the actual "label" is written in my html file for GSA to crawl from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove the "inline" and have the GSA index the binary file format (they do that really well).